# Vue js .bind does not work while passing callback to vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

This works when I pass `redirectCallback` to vuex store:

```
  var router = this.$router;
  var redirectCallback = () => {
    return userApi.deleteContact(userId, contactId).then(res => {
      store.commit("modals/HIDE_DANGER_MODAL");
      if (!res) {
        // error occurred
        return store.commit("modals/SHOW_DRROR_MODAL", {
          modalTitle: "Failed",
          modalBody: "Couldn't delete contact"
        });
      }
      store.commit("modals/SET_CUSTOM_CLOSE_OPERATION", function() {
        router.replace("/contacts");
      });
      return store.commit("modals/SHOW_SUCCESS_MODAL", {
        modalTitle: "Success",
        modalBody: "Contact Deleted Successfully!"
      });
    });
  };
```

But If I do it this way, it does not work and I get error `cannot read property .replace of undefined`:

```
  var redirectCallback = () => {
    return userApi.deleteContact(userId, contactId).then(res => {
      store.commit("modals/HIDE_DANGER_MODAL");
      if (!res) {
        // error occurred
        return store.commit("modals/SHOW_DRROR_MODAL", {
          modalTitle: "Failed",
          modalBody: "Couldn't delete contact"
        });
      }
      store.commit("modals/SET_CUSTOM_CLOSE_OPERATION", function() {
        this.$router.replace("/contacts");
      });
      return store.commit("modals/SHOW_SUCCESS_MODAL", {
        modalTitle: "Success",
        modalBody: "Contact Deleted Successfully!"
      });
    });
  };
```

I have just used `this.$router` instead of a local variable in vue component method it does not work.
Here is how I pass the callback to vuex store:

```
  store.commit(
    "modals/SET_DANGEROUS_OPERATION",
    redirectCallback.bind(this)
  );
```

And here is how I invoke the callback:

```
  await store.dispatch("modals/performDangerousOperation");
```

So in short, I just dispatch the "performDangerousOperation" which invokes the callback(promise) and then it shows another modal. That modal has a close button which fires the "performCustomCloseOperation"(that we set in the redirectCallback above).

I just wonder why does the `.bind` does not work here(due to which this.$router is not defined)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the anonymous function creates another `this` which overrides `this` in `redirectCallback`:

```
  store.commit("modals/SET_CUSTOM_CLOSE_OPERATION", function() {
    this.$router.replace("/contacts");
  });
```

Change it to an arrow function should work:

```
  store.commit("modals/SET_CUSTOM_CLOSE_OPERATION", () => {
    this.$router.replace("/contacts");
  });
```